# MS Graph API / Synchronization API - How to set the scope setting?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the AzureAD Portal, in "Enterprise applications ->  -> Provisioning -> Edit Provisioning -> Settings", I can choose a "scope" between "Sync only assigned users and groups" and "Sync all users and groups".

How can I do that with the Graph API? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Pleaes refer [Use accessReviewQueryScope and accessReviewInactiveUsersQueryScope to configure scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/accessreviews-scope-concept#example-1-review-all-users-assigned-to-a-group)

Comment: Hi! How does that relate to the provisioning scope one can set in a Service Principal?

Comment: Hi @jidey, here you can check out this document for providing the scopes and the sevrice principal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-delegatedpermissionclassifications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by chance how to choose between "Sync only assigned users and groups" and "Sync all users and groups" with GraphAPI.

It's actually part of the ServicePrincipal's synchronization secrets, under the `SyncAll` key:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/<ID>/synchronization/secrets

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#servicePrincipals('<ID>')/synchronization/secrets",
    "value": [
        {
            "key": "BaseAddress",
            "value": "https://my.server.com/scim"
        },
        {
            "key": "SecretToken",
            "value": "*"
        },
        {
            "key": "SyncNotificationSettings",
            "value": "{\"Enabled\":false,\"DeleteThresholdEnabled\":false,\"HumanResourcesLookaheadQueryEnabled\":false}"
        },
        {
            "key": "SyncAll",
            "value": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found it in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/app-provisioning/skip-out-of-scope-deletions.md